# gnuplottex and auto-pst-pdf don't work together

Tags: auto-pst-pdf, gnuplottex

I just started to work with `gnuplottex` to have nice diagrams in my thesis. In my pretests everything worked fine, but when implementing the diagram into my thesis it did not work anymore. While putting up a minimal example I found out, that the packages `gnuplottex` and `auto-pst-pdf` (which I need for other diagrams) don't work together. Can you give me a hint how to get a work around or what I am doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[runs=2,crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage[miktex,shell]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{Ein Kapitel}
Ein bisschen Text.
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex, terminaloptions={color dashed size 15cm,15cm}]
set key below
set boxwidth 0.75 absolute
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid 1.0 border lt -1
set xtics 1 rotate by -75
set yrange [0:100]
set xtics scale 0
set xrange [0:30]
unset y2tics
set grid ytics
set ylabel 'Umsatz, Ausbeute / \%'
set noborder
plot 'test.dat' using 3:xtic(1) ti "qw", '' using 4:xtic(1) ti "we", '' using 5:xtic(1) ti "rt", '' using 6:xtic(1) ti "fg", '' using 7:xtic(1) ti "vc", '' using 8:xtic(1) ti "nb", '' using 9:xtic(1) ti "jh", '' using 2:xtic(1) with points pointtype 5 ti "mj" 
\end{gnuplot}
\section{Ein Kapitel}
Ein bisschen mehr Text.
\end{document}
```

I know, this is not a real minimal example as I left the plot quite complete. But everything works fine when I remove the package `auto-pst-pdf`. When I add it, the file `foo-pics.pdf` does not contain the graph but the whole document just without the graph. This is then implemented at the place of the graph.

I am using MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXnicCenter 2.02. You can find my datafile below for testing purpose:

```
Katalysator mj qw we rt fg vc nb jh
" a" 99 0 0 0 0 68 0 0
" b" 96 0 0 0 0 53 0 0
" c" 53 0 0 0 0 21 0 0
" d" 79 0 0 0 0 7 0 0
" e" 77 0 0 0 0 22 0 0
" f" 89 0 0 0 0 15 0 0
" g" 100 0 0 0 0 35 0 0
" h" 100 0 0 0 46 0 0 0
" i" 96.72 1.56 14.95 12.86 23.52 8.63 6.87 0
" j" 98.58 0.47 2.49 11.31 61.03 0.6 0.19 1.92
" k" 100 0 0 0 43 0 0 0
" l" 58.01 0 0 0 0 4.12 0 0
" m" 49 0 0 0 0 2.03 0 0
" n" 47.26 0 0 0 0 4.53 0 0
" o" 64.06 0 0 0 0 1.72 0 0
" p" 61.92 0 0 0 0.34 14.5 0 0
" q" 57.24 0 0 0 0.05 15.71 0 0
" r" 100 0 0 0 0 70.2 0 0
" s" 100 0 0 0 1.59 44.17 0 0
" t" 100 0 0 0 1.13 81.74 0 0
" u" 100 0 0 0 14.57 26.04 0 0
" v" 100 0 0 0 2.53 64.68 0 0
" w" 31.34 0 0.31 8.97 0.16 18.77 0.27 0.36
" x" 92.05 0 8.85 14.09 8.96 31.42 9.33 1.8
" y" 57.67 0 2.79 14.44 11.9 7.33 0.78 9.65
" z" 95.74 0 0 0 1.47 0 0 0
" aa" 89.65 0.34 0.97 14.59 0.16 3.7 0 10.44
" bb" 97.5 0.59 9.7 26.57 39.75 2.21 0.95 1.88
" cc" 100 1.8 15.06 12.46 40.46 0.46 0.34 0
" dd" 26.26 0 0 11.96 0 17.61 0 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the error message you're getting? Have you tried loading the two packages in the opposite order in which you're loading them now?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I don't get an error, jut a warning. That says `'foo-pics.pdf' contains 2 pages but 1 pages are requested: File 'foo-pics.pdf' is no more valid! Recreate it.`
I did not try different orders of loading the packages before, but checked for it now. It does not make a difference if I exchange `gnuplottex` and `auto-pst-pdf`. Also loading `auto-pst-pdf` last doesn't change anything.

Comment: Are you using latex or pdflatex? It looks like `auto-pst-pdf` is processing the generated figures.

Comment: I am using pdflatex.

I looked again through my complete file to see, where I need `auto-pst-pdf`. I have schemes with chemical compounds which I want to number automaticaly (done by `chemstyle`) . `auto-pst-pdf` allows me to work with .eps files with pdflatex.

Comment: Have you tried a non-eps terminal for the gnuplot figures?

Comment: No I only tried with `epslatex`. I'm new to gnuplot, so I did lot of reading but even more of try and error. What would you recomend? `cairolatex`with the option pdf?

Comment: I would use something that produces PDFs directly. I think that will solve the problem.

Comment: My minimal example worke with `cairolatex` and the pdf option, so thank you already for your advise. Unfortunately my main document doesn't and from the first glance I don't understand the errors. As soon as I have more information or need more help I will be back.

Comment: Oh my ... I just did really stupid mistake, the suggested solution also works fine in my main document. Thank you again for your help, Lars! Do you want to post your suggestion as answer? Then I can mark it as accepted. Or are the points not so important? (I'm new to this chat as well)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer so it's easier for other people to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `auto-pst-pdf` is processing the figures generated by `gnuplottex` incorrectly. Not sure what's causing this, but you can avoid the problem by using a gnuplot terminal that supports PDF output so that this conversion is unnecessary.